# Custom Module Layout Problem

Tags: module, magento2.2, custom

I've created a custom Magento 2 Module and I am facing a problem of URL returning blank page If I am calling the block from template file using layout

Magento Version : 2.2.4

URL Trying to visit : 127.0.0.1/magento/whatsapp/index/display

It returns a blank page.

here is my files structure:

Mahran/Whatsapp/Block/Display.php

```
<?php
namespace Mahran\Whatsapp\Block;
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Mahran\Whatsapp\Controller\Index\Display.php

```
<?php

namespace Mahran\Whatsapp\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Mahran/Whatsapp/view/frontend/layout/whatsapp_index_display.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Mahran\Whatsapp\Block\Display" name="whatsapp_display" template="Mahran_Whatsapp::sayhello.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Mahran/Whatsapp/templates/frontend/templates/sayhello.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * @var \Mahran\Whatsapp\Block\Display $block
 */

echo $block->sayHello();
```

Comment: Change mahran\whatsapp to Mahran\Whatsapp

Comment: @SohelRana Sadly this did't work I have another action called Test.php that I echo "Hello World" directly inside and it's working fine.

Comment: @MostafaMahran does that work as per my updates made to question?

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal I made exactly these updates but still it's the same

Comment: Ok, let me check it further.. I hope you have already added the routes.xml

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal here is the routes for you to check 


`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="whatsapp" frontName="whatsapp">
            <module name="Mahran_Whatsapp" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code and added at below public repo:
https://bitbucket.org/hemant2586/mahran_whatsapp/src/master/

Its working fine for me, download and check with it..

Comment: It's working now ! can I understand the changes you made because I can't seem to find any difference in code that my eye could catch.

Comment: Not sure but it may be CamelCase issue, would suggest to check if you update the directory name accordingly and block class name in xml correctly..  <block class="Mahran\Whatsapp\Block\Display" (note the naming case)

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @Himmat Paliwal